# Javascript Dates : change time

Tags: javascript, date

Do you know an elegant way to change the time in a Date Object in javascript

The strangness is those setters that return Number object

```
var date = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

date is a Number not a date..

so let's say I have a date
    var date = new Date()

and I want to change time

Thank you

Comment: var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1332403882588);

Comment: Sorry.. no it wont work.. I was not specific enough

Comment: Then use setHours(),setMinutes(),setSeconds()

Comment: if fact I dont vote for a useful comment

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours( 0,0,0,0 );
```

[`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) actually has two effects:

1. It modifies the object it is applied to
2. It returns the new timestamp of that date object

So in your case, just create the object and set the time separately afterwards. You can then ignore the return value entirely, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Create date.  Left empty, will default to 'now'
var myDate = new Date();

// Set hours
myDate.setHours(7);

// Then set minutes
myDate.setMinutes(15);

// Then set seconds
myDate.setSeconds(47);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date()
date.setUTCHours(15,31,01);
```

This will return a time of 15::31:01

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setutchours.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it, get midnight of the current day for example:-

```
var date = new Date(); // Datetime now
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(date); // Midnight today 00:00:00.000
```

The `setHours` function returns a timestamp rather than a `Date` object, but it will modify the original `Date` object.

The timestamp can be used to initialize new date objects and perform arithmetic.

```
var timestamp = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var date = new Date(timestamp); // Midnight today 00:00:00.000
var hourBeforeMidnight = timestamp - (60 * 60 * 1000);
var otherDate = new Date(hourBeforeMidnight); // Date one hour before
```

The timestamp is the same value you would get if you called `getTime`.

```
var timestamp = date.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

This Snippet will convert the time to 0:0:0 which is needed if you are going to filter data from zeroth hour of the day. 
Useful for ODATA filtering on Dates

```js
                    var a = new Array();
     var b = new Array();
     var c = new Array();
     var date = new Date().toJSON();
     a = date.split("T");
     a = a[0];
     b = a.split("-");
     var currentDate = new Date(b[0],b[1] - 1, b[2] + 1 ,-19,30,0).toJSON();
     c = currentDate.split(".");
     var newDate = c[0];
console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const date = (new Date()).setHours(0,0,0,0);
```